# KDE Dolphin: All file associations lost and "open with" provides no options

Tags: kde, dolphin, file-associations

The other day, KDE/Dolphin seem to have lost all file associations, and the "open with" dialog box no longer presents a list of my applications. If I type an application shortcut name like "kate" into the dialog box, it will open it with kate.

Presumably, some config file got corrupted somehow, but which file is that? And can I rebuild it automatically from the list of applications in my start menu?

[image: None of my applications are available to choose]

Edit: It seems this is only happening in certain folders.

Edit: I tried the thing in the comment DK Bose and that fixed it.

```
james@Q35~/nfs-cloud/websites/test_flask_site/static $ locate mimeapps.list
/home/james/.config/mimeapps.list
/home/james/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
/home/james/Downloads/haroopad-v0.13.1-x64/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list
james@Q35~/nfs-cloud/websites/test_flask_site/static $ mv /home/james/.config/mimeapps.list /home/james/.config/mimeapps.list.bak
james@Q35~/nfs-cloud/websites/test_flask_site/static $ mv /home/james/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list /home/james/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list.bak
james@Q35~/nfs-cloud/websites/test_flask_site/static $ mv /home/james/Downloads/haroopad-v0.13.1-x64/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list /home/james/Downloads/haroopad-v0.13.1-x64/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list.bak
```

[image: all is well]

Comment: What do you see with `locate mimeapps.list`? Then, temporarily rename each `mimeapps.list` to `mimeapps.list.bak`, log out and log back in. The system will rebuild these files. After that, you shouldn't have the problem.

Comment: Yes, that did it, thanks! Maybe repost this comment as an answer.
I'm still curious what might have caused these files to get messed up though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in 2011 and the [advice](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861067) to delete or rename the existing `mimeapps.list`, log out and log back in worked for me. I can't explain why it happened in the first place!

There are two user-level locations:

- $HOME/.config and
- $HOME/.local/share/applications

The [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_MIME_Applications) indicates that the second location is deprecated:

> Tip: Although deprecated, several applications still read/write to `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. To simplify maintenance, simply symlink it to `~/.config/mimeapps.list`:

```
ln -s ~/.config/mimeapps.list ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

Comment: So, I had this issue again, and this time I noticed that on Clear Linux (with KDE),  mimeapps.list is only created in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. I did have one in `~/.config` before, but it is not recreated on re-login (only the "deprecated" one). Which is odd because Clear Linux is rolling-release, so it should be up-to-date/